# Align an anchor to the right

Tags: html, css

Consider the following:

```
<a>a</a><a>b</a>
```

How can I align the second anchor (b) to the right?

**PS:** float is an abuse in this situation. It's not made for this and it causes some problems, so I need other more reasonable solution.

Comment: isn´t there any wrapping element?  why is floating not reasonable for you ?

Comment: cause i have a div below, and if i use float, the margin between the 1st anchor and the div and the margin between the second anchor and the div are not the same + at first sight it sounds not good "float"

Comment: abuot text-align right, it doesn't work, because it alignes the text insid the anchor but i want to align the anchor itself

Comment: you need to give width to anchor and it will work

Comment: "float is an abuse in this situation" -- nonsense

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd need separate containers.

```html
<p>
    <span>
        <a>Left</a>
    </span>
    <span class="align-right">
        <a>Right</a>
    </span>
</p>
```

```css
p {font-size:0; /* Fixes inline block spacing */  }
span { width:50%; display:inline-block; }
span.align-right { text-align:right; }

span a { font-size:16px; }
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xEVdM/2/).

Comment: it complicate things if we have 4 anchors and i want to align the two last, so i need a solution that's general

Comment: In that case you'd stick your two right-aligned anchors in the right-aligned span. `<span><a>a</a></span><span class="align-right"><a>b</a><a>c</a></span>`. I've added a JSFiddle example to my post.

Answer (score 28):

**Just do this:**

```
style="float:right"
```

**Like:**

```
<div>
   <a href="#Equipment" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-mini">Equipment</a>
   <a href="#Model" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-mini" style="float:right">Model</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/umerqureshi/0jx7kf1L/

Comment: Re *"Just do this"*: Still, an explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27740253/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 8):

Try this CSS,

**Using CSS3 nth-child()**

```
a:nth-child(2) {
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: right;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/opexim/3/edit

Note: nth-child is a CSS3 and won't work on older browsers like IE6, 7 and 8

**Support for old browsers**

Set `class` to second `<a>` anchor element and apply the CSS.

```
<a>a</a><a class="right">b</a>


a.right {
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: right;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: you are making the b is in the next lign, and this will be so complicated if we need to align more than 1 element

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can make something like this: `<a>a</a><a class="right">b</a>`

And CSS like this:

```css
a.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: If there is no wrapping element where do you consider the second link to appear? :)

Comment: this is not good, cause imagine i have 3 anchors and i want to align the two last, your solution will complicate things  in this situation

Comment: @user2080105 if the problem might involve more than 2 anchors you should mention that in the question

Answer (score 1):

Try and use *[:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)*:

```css
a:nth-child(2) {
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: right;
   width: 100%;
}
```

I don’t know if this works for the older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below code:

```
<a>a</a><a align="right">b</a>

  <a>a</a><a style="text-align:right">b</a>
```

Comment: abuot text-align right, it doesn't work, because it alignes the text insid the anchor but i want to align the anchor itself

Answer (score 0):

Assign a `class` or `id` to the 'b' containing anchor and give `margin-left:100%` to it.

For example:

```
.second{margin-left:100%;}
```

**or else**

```
a:nth-child(2){margin-left:100%;}
```

**or else**

you can also do like mentioned below:

**css**

```
a:nth-child(1){display:inline-block;width:50%;text-align:left;float:left;}
a:nth-child(2), .second{display:inline-block;width:50%;text-align:right;}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ojasik/1/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="mydiv">
    <a class ="mylink"> test </a>
</div>
```

```css
.mydiv {
    text-align: left;
}
```

You must enter your styles for the 'a' tag `algin` give to 'div'.

Comment: What do you mean by *"for the 'a' tag algin give to 'div'"* (seems incomprehensible)? By *"algin"*, do you mean *"[align](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/align#Verb)"*? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67762264/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).