# How to right align a single child in div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has two child elements. A span and a div which contain's an X. My goal is to right align the X.

https://jsfiddle.net/Le8hn0am/

[image]

What it should look like

[image]

I've tried suggestions from [How to right align a hyperlink in a <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834047/how-to-right-align-a-hyperlink-in-a-div) and [How to align 3 divs (left/center/right) inside another div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603700/how-to-align-3-divs-left-center-right-inside-another-div) but haven't had any luck

What I've tried

```
- float:right;
- margin-left: auto;
```

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: There is a lot of CSS here which rather obscures what it actually wanted. Do you need it all?

Comment: [How to align 3 divs (left/center/right) inside another div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603700/how-to-align-3-divs-left-center-right-inside-another-div) is 11 years old ! 3years old for the first link.
Forget about float (at least for layouts) Use display: flex or display: grid. In your case grid would be my first choice

Comment: @CedricCholley the age of a question doesn't matter. That 11 years old question is and will remain valid in 11 years from now

Comment: @TemaniAfif In some cases questions could remain valid for 11 years and more, you are right. This is not one of the cases, CSS has changed a lot in the past... way less than 11 years. Now a days using `float` to create layout should be avoid, there are (much much much) better ways: `flex`and `grid`

Comment: @CedricCholley I invite you to read that question then (it seems you didn't)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is too much CSS to style such a simple object. In any case ...

1. Add `position:relative;` to `#DIV_1 {`
2. Add `position: absolute;` and `right: 7px;` to `#DIV_3 {`

[Your fiddle with my changes](https://jsfiddle.net/xen4wgta/)

Answer (score 1):

What could be done is to use `display: grid` on the parent (div) with 2 columns. the 1st column is set to `auto` and the 2nd to `1fr` to use all the remaining space. Align column content to right (`justify-items: end`) and *Voilà* ;-)

```css
/* new CSS code */
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  justify-items: end;
}

/* simplified code from your original fiddle  */
div {
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 16px;
  width: 67.5781px;
  background-color: rgb(179, 229, 255);
  font: 600 12px / 12px "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 2px 6px;
}


span {
  color: rgb(15, 27, 49);
}

a {
  color: rgb(0, 85, 139);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>days</span>
  <a>X</a>
</div>
```

PS I've simplified the original code.

Answer (score 0):

You could just simply add the display flex property to the DIV and reduce the padding-left so that the x is always at the end of the div:

```
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rdy3xbc7/1/)